# How to fetch processor CPU flags in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, processor

How to fetch processor CPU flags in C# .net ?

I am particularly looking for VMX bit/flag.

Comment: CPU flags : fpu tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe cid xtpr .....


For example here meaning of "FPU" flag is -->*** 
x87 Floating Point Unit built into the CPU. This is where most mathematically intense calculations take place. Used to be a separate chip on the 80486SX and earlier (called the 80487 or 80387, etc. 80486DX had FPU built-in as well). All Pentium CPUs and later have this functionality built in.***

Comment: You mean the feature flags. CPU flags could be something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps writing a .NET-accessible wrapper around [__cpuid?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the WinRing0 library.